# User testing, novice outperforms experts

Tags: usability-testing, evaluation

Happy new year to all! Recently we are working on the findability of content elements by running tree testing. At the results, we encountered that novice users are better at finding correct options comparing to regular users. Have you ever bump into something like this before? How can I delve deeper the effect of level of expertise? Now, we are also running face to face usability testings with the same system.  What qualitative would you be looking at to be able to explain novice outperforming?

Comment: Are there any other interfaces user visits and which may learn the user other pattern and make him forget where to find elements once he returns back? 
Do you have same category of users for novice user and expert user, meaning are they same profile? What was size of your group you did the test, what metrics do you read to make such conclusion?

Comment: To be more precise, we are testing a mobile banking app. All participants were using a bank app, 20 participants were clients of other banks hence using a different bank app than our interest in testing and 30 participants were the client of the bank and using the app under investigation. Profile for both groups has the same diversity on age and volume of transaction for a bank app. I was consucting treetesting on optimalworkshop so my metric was task completion rate. Thanks for your interest let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common behavior. Expert users already know the system (at least they suppose they know it). Once you introduce small changes, tests seems skewed due to expert user's inertia.

On the opposite side, novice users are expecting something new, so they focus on the tasks way more tan expert users, which in turn gives you this kind of results.

This typically happens when changes are small. For novice users, the system is new, so they need to pay as much attention as possible. For expert users, the system seems to be the same, so they don't care as much. There are quite deep psychological mechanisms involved so I won't go further, but if you're interested, you can read more on this subject doing a search on [**Equivalence Relation**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2779070/)

You can read about more about this on Jakob Nielsen's article **[Testing Expert Users](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/testing-expert-users/)** or if you want to go deeper and understand the mechanisms that CAUSE this behavior, try [**Equivalence classes and insensitivity to contingencies: Sequence of learning by instructions and by contingencies**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292990909_Clases_de_equivalencia_e_insensibilidad_a_las_contingencias_Secuencia_de_aprendizaje_por_instrucciones_y_por_contingencias_Equivalence_classes_and_insensitivity_to_contingencies_Sequence_of_learning_b) by  Doctor Mariana Arismendi (research is in Spanish, but you can read the abstract or access the English version if you have a Research Gate account. *Disclaimer: the author is my wife and associate*)

Comment: Thanks a lot Devin. Just wanted to add that the testing system did not have any changes, it has been the same for 3 years. We just wanted to test exact current app. I will definitely go through your suggestion to investigate further. Would be amazing if you add any comments or ideas which comes after my extra information about the system that includes no change for 3 years.

Comment: @IzlemAkman, when I say "small", it can be considered that "without changes" will have more or less the same predictable result if the application to be tested is an application with a high friction and information overload (for example ... a financial application). I mention the part of **Ratio of equivalence** for this reason: when it comes to testing, there is a tested and proven direct inverse correlation between the level of user's experience with the system and the difficulty of that system.

Comment: appreciate the explanation. I think I got the initial idea, need to check a bit more on ratio of equivalence to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

If your research showed you something unexpected, it probably hints some further research is needed.

Your plan of doing usability testing is great since you can start to understand some of the whys. Make sure the testings address the questions created by the tree testing. Maybe it was due to current users judging the new navigation based on the old one, who knows.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the answer. I am trying to focus how participants find a content while performing tasks on user testing this is actually mimicing the tree testing ia go through. Let’s see. I would be grateful if you can recommend any literature to give me some theories on expertise level on use